# API for apple.com purchase/order history

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, web-scraping, app-store

Does anyone know of an API for fetching order history from apple.com specifically I am looking for a way to pull invoice ID's and Serial numbers from orders for physical hardware such as mac laptops.

Then will use this information in another system but cant seem to find any API or way to get this information programmatically without scraping.

Comment: With the strict Privacy rules Apple has in place, it would really suprise me if there was a publicly available API to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) website and searched for the public API's. There is no available API for what you're trying to do. You could always try to use Web Scraping to get an API. I'm not certain if this is against the Apple TOS, but you could try doing that.